# How to light all faces of 3D object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I light every face of my 3D object with lights?

I have one direction light in my scene and I am using lightweight render pipeline. While my direction light hitting from front to my 3D model behind it becomes black. Removing shadow does not effect. My 3D objects behind always become darker.

How to make light every face?

Removing shadows does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the unlit LWRP shader.

To select and use this Shader:

In your Project, create or find the Material you want to use the Shader on. Select the Material. A Material Inspector window opens.

Click Shader, and select Lightweight Render Pipeline > Unlit.